# Will users need a Skype account to use Skype SDK on third-party app?

Tags: skypedeveloper

I am currently developing an mobile app that will use the Skype SDK for video chat functionality. Will users of the app need a Skype account in order to use this feature?

Answer (score 0):

No they will not. Only the "agents" who initially creates a meeting will need a SfB account/license.